# JAR to EXE(working with look and feel)

Tags: java, exe, look-and-feel

I have used a different look and feel desing in my project but how can I convert it to an EXE and maintain the design created? I used Launch4j to turn it to a EXE but it keeps the "Metal" look and feel.

Comment: how did you set your custom look and feel? Is maybe a dependency (jar-file) of your custom look and feel missing on the class path when you start it with launch4j?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the command line argument in launch4j. That would be something along the line of `-Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel`.
The problem with this approach is that it isn't really crossplatform. I suspect you want the *system l&f*. That can be done per code:

```
try {
     UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
}
catch(Exception e) {...}
```

Just put that on the first line of your program.

*Note that you can also specify other l&f's.*

---

#### Edit #1

Of course you can specify your *own* l&f aswell if that is what you are looking for. Just pass the class name:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.someproject.somepackage.MyAwesomeLookAndFeel");
```

Comment: I'm using Jtattoo l&f and i'm calling it like this:

try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.aluminium.AluminiumLookAndFeel");
            
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Grafic.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }